# Как пишется "невидавшей" - вместе или раздельно?

Tags: старая-орфография

Едва заметная пыль сбивалась под ногами, взвиваясь вверх маленьким облачком с белой, невидавшей давно дождя, дороги.

Answer (score 1):

Едва заметная пыль сбивалась под ногами, взвиваясь вверх маленьким облачком с белой, не видавшей давно дождя, дороги.

Раздельное написание НЕ с причастием при наличии зависимого слова "давно".

Примечание:

Не очень понятна перестановка наречия, сравнить: Едва заметная пыль сбивалась под ногами, взвиваясь вверх маленьким облачком с белой, давно не видавшей дождя, дороги.

Comment: Мне больше нравится авторский вариант. У вас более "приглаженный", это далеко не всегда плюс. Кстати, последняя-то запятая зачем?

Comment: Оборот можно обособлять или не обособлять - это решает автор. В необособленном варианте мы имеем однородные отношения между определениями (они раскрывают одну тему), а при обособлении оборот поясняет первое определение (почему дорога белая).

Comment: Что касается инверсии наречия, то она нарушает плавность речи, ударение переходит на причастие, и язык "спотыкается" при чтении. А какой в этом художественный смысл, я не вижу.

Comment: Естественно, это же одна фраза, вот и не видите.

Comment: Если одна и та же фраза, то зачем инверсия? Чем вам приглянулся авторский вариант с нарушением обычного порядка слов?

Comment: Именно нарушением и приглянулся.

Comment: Вам нравится ВСЁ "неправильное"? Я могу согласиться с тем, что инверсии - предмет полезный и в художественном стиле очень распространенный, они делают текст ярким, объемным. Только это должна быть правильная "неправильность", а не какая-нибудь, когда образности не прибавилось, а читать стало неудобнее.

Answer (score 1):

"Не видавшая" всегда пишется раздельно. Просто нет такого слова – "невидавшая".

Кстати, нужна ли последняя запятая?